# Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE lint error on Android 12

Tags: java, android

After changing compileSdkVersion to 31, I now get some lint errors saying

> Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE Must be one of: ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE, ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_COARSE

for this line of code:

```
locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

I changed it to `ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE` and now it says

> Field requires API level 31

I wrapped it around an `if SDK version >= 31` then use `ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE` else use `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE`. Now I still get a lint error on `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE`. How do you even fix this properly? And why did Google decide to make this change in the first place and break things is beyond me..

Example to reproduce this error:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, ProviderProperties.POWER_USAGE_LOW, ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE);
} else {
    locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
}
```

Comment: "How do you even fix this properly?" -- you might want to provide a [mcve] showing your final code.

Comment: Just added an example now, thanks!

Comment: That does not show your final code, from "I wrapped it around an if SDK version >= 31". Ideally, `LocationManagerCompat` would have its own `addTestProvider()` that covers this case. Unfortunately, it does not appear to have that, at least through `androidx.core:core:1.9.0-alpha04`. My best guess, without seeing the final code, is that you still need to add a `@SuppressLint`, perhaps due to a bug in the Lint check.

Comment: Sorry about that, changed it now. Yeah, seems like it is a bug. I think it would be safe to just use ```Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE``` as their values are exactly the same? Thanks

Comment: In the end, the value is an `int`. Only the actual value should get compiled into the app, since these are constants. So, yeah, it should be safe to just stick with the `Criteria` values if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the method (which also provides the fallback) with `@TargetApi(31)` and/or `@SuppressLint("Deprecated")`. One can either provide backwards compatibility alike that - or keep old implementations in some `legacy` build-type ...which may be something to consider, when it becomes a little much backwards-compatibility code.